# Progress on: CJK ctexart LuaLaTeX. Either characters shows "F" or Author has "UU" (See picture)

Tags: luatex, cjk, chinese, japanese, ctex

```
\documentclass[UTF8,fontset=fandol,disablejfam]{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm}
% \setCJKsansfont{Noto Serif CJK JP}
% \setCJKmonofont{Noto Serif CJK JP}
\usepackage[margin=1.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{soul} % for strike through \st{}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.55}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.45ex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % Strike Chinese
\usepackage{emoji}

% \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ℕ}{\mathbb{N}}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{志远的胡言乱语}
\author{刘志远}
\date{June 2023}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

気に入ったの一つですね。

\texttt{志远的胡言乱语}

\textbf{気に入ったの一つですね。}

\textsc{気に入ったの一つですね。}



\end{document}
```

New problems encountered:

Okay, it has now fixed my body texts, BUT all Chinese sections are ruined.

Want to: Make the main environment Chinese, but at a selected place to have Japanese.

[image: Problem is here]

Comment: You need a font having all the characters in the document.

Comment: Well how would I do that? Tried to import SongTi but the size is way too big for overleaf. Or how to combine ipxaem and some other fonts?